# Gradle build duplicate entry

Tags: java, android

I'm building a project with a library [aFileChooser](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser). I have imported it to my studio, created a "build.gradle" for it (because I had another issue "no configuration named default" or smth like that). With the new build file the build is going ok. But deploying an apk to launch is not.

I'm getting an issue about duplicate entry while I'm trying to deploy my app to the phone. The exact issue is:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/hardware/display/DisplayManagerCompat.class

I've already seen a lot of questions on SO about duplicates but none of the answers helped me. I have tried excluding the "support-v4" module, tried removing dependencies and so on. Nothing seems to work and the problem stays there.

Here are my gradle files:

**aFileChooser build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'}
 }


  apply plugin: 'android-library'

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 22
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

}
   }
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
}
```

**app build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ua.com.vendetta8247.testmate"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
    compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1')
    compile ('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1')
    compile ('com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1')
    compile ('com.android.support:design:22.2.1')

    compile (project(':libs:aFileChooser'))
}
```

**General build**

```
sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I get the exception no matter what I try. If I delete the "dependencies" in aFileChooser the files cannot be compiled as they're missing v4 files.

**Update 1**

I have run `gradle -q dependencies yourProject:dependencies --configuration compile` as suggested in one answer. Here is my output:

```
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1
+--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.1
+--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1
+--- com.android.support:design:22.2.1
|    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1
\--- project :aFileChooser
     \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1
          \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.1
```

Comment: have you tried to delete this `compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1')` from your app build file ?

Comment: @DanCantir Just tried it. Doesn't help at all. Though I'm pretty surprised it didn't crash the project. Because I'm using support v7 extensively

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After about 10 hours of searching through SO, Google docs and other sources I have found that this issue may be just project related. The solution was simple:

```
gradle clean
gradle assembleDebug
```

and that's it.

Now I will explain why this happened. After importing the library I had to create my own build script and mess with some properties inside the library. I suppose that Android Studio installed a newer version of Gradle without removing previous configurations or something close to that. That's why I suggest those who have similar issue to clean their project every time you add a new library

Comment: The Comment you have added is wrong in my view :- When using terminal in Android Studio the                                                                                                                                            gradle clean will not run instead of this - gradlew clean will work and same for gradlew assembleDebug

Comment: Ah yes, the good old clean. In Android Studio this can be done with `Build > Clean Project` and `Build > Rebuild Project`.